# Add and retrieving data from here maps

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, dictionary, here-api

I working with windows phone app and I wonder, is there any way I can retrieve data from here maps like bus station or airport and showing that data into my apps?

and also to add some place information into here maps? like adding location in foursquare?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not certain which maps offering this question is about, since There are no HERE maps API offering for the Windows Phone 7 as such, the maps API there were using Bing Maps instead.

Anyways, if this is HERE Maps question, then the SDK API does not offer any Functionality for what you are asking, however there is [Places API with HERE](https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/places), which could give you the places and you could search those places by category.

For adding places, I suppose that currently the API does not offer any interface which could be used by normal 3rd party developer.

Comment: I did actually make a C# wrapper fro the Places REST service, and its published at: https://github.com/DrJukka/Windows_Phone/tree/master/places-wrapper though have to admit that its not finalized project, and currently not dedicating any time for it either.