# How to add new place to Here Maps via API?

Tags: here-api, here-maps-rest

Is possible to add new place to Here maps?

Early wrote that it is impossible ([Add and retrieving data from here maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20867366/add-and-retrieving-data-from-here-maps)), but it was in 2014. 
How are things now?

In the end, I would like to create new places/location like Google maps.
Thank you all in advance for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can add Places by locating and providing the place details in https://mapcreator.here.com/. The Here Reviewer Team will review it and add the place post verification. You will be able to view the status of your request as well. Hope this helps!
[image]

To make changes or provide feedback about an existing place in Here Maps use the Feedback API. Read more about it here - https://developer.here.com/documentation/map-feedback/topics/example-place-feedback.html

Comment: Can I send data about existing places (as example, searched with Places (Search) AP) to the place post verificaton from my Web App not visiting the site https://mapcreator.here.com/?

Comment: As mentioned in the last point above, you can send feedback about places already in Here Maps. To make changes or provide feedback about an existing place in Here Maps use the Feedback API. Read more about it here - https://developer.here.com/documentation/map-feedback/topics/example-place-feedback.html

Comment: How about to do this via request using Map Feedback about a missing place https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/rest/map_feedback/map-feedback-about-a-missing-place?

Comment: You could use that as well. It has the same flow as in creating it via mapcreator. But if you are the owner of the place then mapcreator is preferred.

Comment: Thanks for answer.

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport If I add something to the map how much time does it take to appear in the public APIs? For example, I add a small Railway Station, when will it appear in the Nearest Station search API as a result? I didn't want to ask this question separately, this semmed to be the most relevant place to ask :)